# Как запретить срабатывание onBindViewHolder при каждом скролле?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Подобные вопросы уже много раз задавались тут, но имеющиеся ответы не решают моей проблемы.

Итак, есть RecyclerView. Наполняется вьюхами, в которых создаются другие вьюхи и наполняются данными. Допустим, необходимо создать только одну строку с пользовательской информацией. После скролла вниз созданная вьюшка клонируется и добавляется к предыдущей. Более наглядно на скрине:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавление в onBindViewHolder holder.setIsRecyclable(false) решает проблему, но появляются ужасные лаги.

В общем, подскажите, пожалуйста, либо как убрать лаги, либо как запретить клонирование созданных вьюшек. А то я уже в отчаянии.

**Адаптер**

```
public class RecipesRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipesRVAdapter.RecipesViewHolder> {

    private List<RecipeModel> recipesModelList;
    public static ArrayList<String> arr;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private SharedPreferences spDates;
    private Date date;
    private ScheduleClient scheduleClient;
    private Context context;

    public RecipesRVAdapter(List<RecipeModel> recipesModelList, ScheduleClient scheduleClient) {
        this.recipesModelList = recipesModelList;
        this.scheduleClient = scheduleClient;
        arr = new ArrayList<>();
        Helper.initStockValuesInArray(arr);
        date = new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public RecipesRVAdapter.RecipesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.preset_fragment, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        spDates = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "recipes_dates", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return new RecipesViewHolder(v);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecipesViewHolder holder, int i) {
       // holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        final String recipeName = recipesModelList.get(i).getName().substring(11);
        if (spDates.contains(recipeName)) {
            if (compareDates(recipeName, spDates.getString(recipeName, ""))) {
                holder.imAlert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        holder.presetFragName.setText(recipeName);
        holder.presetFragNicStrangeValue.setText(String.valueOf(recipesModelList.get(i).getNicStrange()));
        holder.presetFragVGnicotine.setText(String.valueOf(recipesModelList.get(i).getVgNic()));
        holder.presetFragPGnicotine.setText(String.valueOf(recipesModelList.get(i).getPgNic()));
        holder.presetFragADnicotine.setText(String.valueOf(recipesModelList.get(i).getAdNic()));
        holder.presetFragVGvalue.setText(String.valueOf(recipesModelList.get(i).getVgBase()));
        holder.presetFragPGvalue.setText(String.valueOf(recipesModelList.get(i).getPgBase()));
        holder.presetFragADvalue.setText(String.valueOf(recipesModelList.get(i).getAdBase()));
        holder.presetAmountValue.setText(String.valueOf(recipesModelList.get(i).getAmountBase()));
        holder.presetNicotineValue.setText(String.valueOf(recipesModelList.get(i).getAmountNic()));
        holder.flavours = recipesModelList.get(i).getFlavours();
        holder.isPercent = recipesModelList.get(i).isPercent();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            holder.menuBtn.bringToFront();
        }


        if (holder.flavours != null) {
            int indexOfBkt;
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : holder.flavours.entrySet()) {
                if (arr.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    // noinspection UnnecessaryContinue
                    continue;
                } else {
                    if (holder.flavorCardView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                        holder.flavorCardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    LinearLayout flavor_linear = (LinearLayout)
                            holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.flavor_linear);
                    View usersFlavorsPreset = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preset_userflavor_fragment,
                            flavor_linear, false);
                    TextView tvUserFlavorPresetName = (TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.
                            findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetName);
                    tvUserFlavorPresetName.setText(entry.getKey());
                    tvUserFlavorPresetName.setSelected(true);
                    String correctedFlavourValue = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());

                    indexOfBkt = correctedFlavourValue.indexOf("[") + 1;
                    if (holder.isPercent) {
                        correctedFlavourValue = correctedFlavourValue.replaceFirst(",", "%");
                        correctedFlavourValue = correctedFlavourValue.substring(indexOfBkt,
                                correctedFlavourValue.indexOf("%") + 1);
                    } else {
                        correctedFlavourValue = correctedFlavourValue.replaceFirst(",",
                                context.getString(R.string.drops_preset));
                        correctedFlavourValue = correctedFlavourValue.substring(indexOfBkt,
                                correctedFlavourValue.indexOf(context.getString(R.string.drops_preset) + 1));
                    }
                    ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetValue)).
                            setText(correctedFlavourValue);
                    flavor_linear.addView(usersFlavorsPreset);
                }
            }
        } else {
            holder.flavorCardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.recipesModelList.size();
    }

    class RecipesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private Button menuBtn;
        private TextView presetFragName, presetFragNicStrangeValue, presetFragVGnicotine, presetFragPGnicotine,
                presetFragADnicotine, presetFragVGvalue, presetFragPGvalue, presetFragADvalue,
                presetAmountValue, presetNicotineValue;
        private HashMap<String, Map.Entry<String, ?>> flavours;
        private CardView flavorCardView;
        private ImageView imAlert;
        Context context;
        private boolean isPercent;

        RecipesViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            menuBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragMenubtn);
            imAlert = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imAlert);
            flavours = new HashMap<>();
            presetFragName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPresetName);
            presetFragNicStrangeValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragNicotineStrangeValue);
            presetFragVGnicotine = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragVGnicotine);
            presetFragPGnicotine = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragPGnicotine);
            presetFragADnicotine = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragADnicotine);
            presetFragVGvalue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragVGvalue);
            presetFragPGvalue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragPGvalue);
            presetFragADvalue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragADvalue);
            presetAmountValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetAmountValue);


presetNicotineValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.presetNicotineValue);
        flavorCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flavorCardView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Необязательно добавлять слово `Решено` в заголовок, это и так понятно из того, что имеется принятый ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто - надо в `onBindViewHolder`, перед добалением вьюх в контейнер просто удалить все уже имеющиеся в нём вьюхи методом `View#removeAllViews()`

Comment: Как всегда решение проблемы элементарное. Спасибо большое)

Comment: а можно ещё один вопрос?) В RecipesViewHolder я вешаю OnClickListener на CardView, который должен разворачивать ExpandableLayout. К примеру, я открыл первый элемент, скролл вниз, первый элемент свернулся обратно и открылся либо второй, либо любой другой. Есть способ как это предотвратить?

Comment: Создайте массив/лист boolean значений размером с кол-во данных в списке. При нажатии - устанавливайте `true\false` для состояния развёрнутости в качестве значения ячейки массива с порядковым номером позиции в адаптере. в onBindViewGolder устанавливайте развёрнутость в зависимости от значения ячейки этого массива.